# Find the radius of the circle and the area of triangle ABC

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let M be the middle point  of the circle and let points A, B, C, D lie on the circle. Find the radius of the circle and the area of triangle ABC.

**Edit:** 
I am having doubts as to the validity of this problem. Namely given the information, the radius seems to be 3.25. But then I cannot reproduce the figure.

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason that points $B$, $C$ and $D$ are blue?

Comment: No, it's just my clumsiness with GeoGebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Critical comment**.-The triangle of the beginning with sides $4,3,2$ determines the center of the circle, $O$, intersection of the line $AB$ with the bisector of the side $AD$. This radius measures less than $3$ (it is $\approx 2.82158$ and is easy to calculate). What I want to say is that the above also determines the $CB$ side that measures about $5.29$ and not $6$. The problem is poorly constructed.

It must be said that the answer given by @pie314271 is correct but taking the $CB$ side equal to $6$ which is not the true length corresponding to $CB$.

The O. P. has writing "I am having doubts as to the validity of this problem". He is not wrong.

Comment: Yay, finally someone has noticed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First, define the intersection of $AB$ and $CD$ to be $X.$ Now, note that angles $AXD$ and $BXC$ are equal. In addition, $ADX$ and $CBX$ are equal angles as well since they are both inscribed angles of the circle. (If you don't know about inscribed angles, you should probably search that up.) This means that $\triangle AXD\sim\triangle CXB.$ This makes $\frac{XD}{XB}=\frac{AD}{BC}=\frac{2}{3},$ so $XB=\frac{9}{2}$ and $AB,$ which is a diameter of the circle, is equal to $AX+XB=\frac{13}{2},$ making the radius half that, or $r=\boxed{\frac{13}{4}}.$

Now, note that since AB is a diameter of the circle, $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle (as C lies on the circle. This is another result of inscribed angles, as $\angle AMB=180^{\circ}.$) This means we can apply the Pythagorean theorem: We have $AC=\sqrt{(\frac{13}{2})^2-6^2}=\frac{5}{2}.$ This makes the area of $\triangle ABC$ equal to $\frac{AC\cdot CB}{2}=\boxed{\frac{15}{2}}.$

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this figure in GeoGebra with a circle of radius 3.25 but the sides don't add up. Namely if X lies on CD then $AX\neq2$.

Comment: With radius $3.25$, $BC$ is very close to a diameter, so $C$ should be quite close to $A$.